# Find a basis to represent a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations

I've been trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $T:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 $ be a linear transformation defined as $T(x,y)=(2x+y,x+3y)$. Prove that a basis $B$ of $\mathbb R^2 $ so that the representing matrix is:
>
> $[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&4\end{bmatrix}$

I'm just not sure where to begin, as I can tell the representing matrix by the standard basis is:

$[T]_E = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix}$

Am I supposed to find where $(2,1) = (1,1)$ and $(1,3) = (1,4)$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily try to find said basis. Do you know anything about similar matrices?

Comment: Do you mean that I should find that they have the same eigenvalues? To see that they're both similar to the same diagonal matrix?

Comment: Okay @Theo Bendit, so I've found that both matrixes have the same characterstic polynomial. But I don't think that neccesarily means that they're similar, does'nt it?

Comment: I think I understand, their characteristic polynomial is the same, therefore they're similar. And because there's similar, there's an inversable Matrix $P$ that makes $[T]_E=P^-1[T]_BP$, and therefore, the matrix $P$ is the matrix to swap basis from $E\rightarrow B$. And then we can say that there is such a B that fills these requirements.

Comment: Characteristic polynomial is not always enough to determine similarity, but it is in this case. Both of these matrices have the same characteristic polynomial with distinct roots, and hence both matrices are similar to the same diagonal matrix, and hence are similar with each other. But other than that, you've got the right idea.

Comment: I just can't see that they're diagonizable. The characteristic polynomial cannot be factored.. $t^2-5t+5$

Comment: It can't be factored over $\Bbb{Q}$, but it can be factored over $\Bbb{R}$. You can work out the specific roots with quadratic formula if you like, but the point is, because the discriminant $(-5)^2 - 4(1)(5) = 5 > 0$, we know that the quadratic has two distinct real roots. This means both matrices have the same pair of distinct irrational eigenvalues, and hence both can be diagonalised into the same diagonal matrix with irrational diagonal entries.

Answer (score 1):

Let the transformation matrix under the standard basis and the standard basis be $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}, E=\{e_1,e_2\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

and the transformation matrix under the new basis be

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&4\end{pmatrix}, \beta=\{u_1,u_2\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

It is known that the columns of B are

$$\begin{split}B&=\begin{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}Au_1\end{bmatrix}_\beta&\begin{bmatrix}Au_2\end{bmatrix}_\beta\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2a+b\\a+3b\end{bmatrix}_\beta&\begin{bmatrix}2c+d\\c+3d\end{bmatrix}_\beta\end{pmatrix}\end{split}$$

where the columns are the tranformation in the standard basis applied to the basis vectors under the new basis, represented in the new basis's coordinates. Thus

$$\begin{split}\begin{pmatrix}2a+b\\a+3b\end{pmatrix}&=1\cdot u_1-1\cdot u_2=\begin{pmatrix}a-c\\b-d\end{pmatrix}\begin{matrix}(1)\\(2)\end{matrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}2c+d\\c+3d\end{pmatrix}&=1\cdot u_1+4\cdot u_2=\begin{pmatrix}a+4c\\b+4d\end{pmatrix}\begin{matrix}(3)\\(4)\end{matrix}\end{split}$$

From equations (1) and (2) you find that

$$\begin{split}c&=-a-b \text{ (1)}\\d&=-2-2b\text{ (2)}\end{split}$$

Plugging these into (3) and (4) you only get identities back

$$\begin{split}-3a-4b&=-3a-4b\text{ (3)}\\
-7b-4a&=-7b-4a\text{ (4)}\end{split}$$

Thus you can choose any a, b, c, d such that equations (1) and (2) are satisfied and that $u_1,u_2$ would be linearly independent. One such choice could be a=1, b=2, thus c=-3, d=-5.

$$\beta=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-3\\-5\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$